# Is it faster to create a copy of a nested dictionary or access it directly when passing into a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm passing a dictionary, one element of which is also a dictionary, to a function.
I want to access the nested dictionary many times within the function,
and so I was wondering whether it would be faster to create a copy of the nested dictionary as a local variable once at the beginning, and access it directly from that point forward,
or to access it by way of the outer dictionary every time.

Comment: No copies needed. Just take a reference to the nested `dict` and use that reference throughout your function.

Comment: "faster to create a copy of the nested dictionary". It almost certainly will not be faster to create an actual [deep] copy of the dictionary. It may be faster to create an extra *reference* to it as a local variable. You probably need to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html to see if it's actually worthwhile in your case.

Comment: I guess it would be faster to create a reference that is called only once but it depends on how python handles dictionaries, also depending on the size the increase in the speed would probably be minimal

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought function parameters were passed in by value

Comment: Function parameters are *always* passed by value, its just that each value, in python, is a reference to an object. This means that passing a parameter is always cheap as it is equivalent of passing a native `int` for the platform.

Comment: Python is not pass by reference or pass by value. It is pass by assignment. You should read this : https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/ to get more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this code:

```py
d = {'nested':{}, 1:[], 2:[], 3:[]}

def f(d):
    n = d['nested']
    for k,v in n.items():
        ...
```

Then calling `f(d)` is cheap, since the reference to `d` is copied as a parameter, but only costs the size of an `int`.

The line `n = d['nested']` costs a little to look-up the key. This cost is best paid once at the beginning of a function rather than paid each time `n` is accessed.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the situation I was facing

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have already accepted the answer. But see this also.
Sometimes it is good to see statistical values to confirm any intuition that you may have. I wrote a little script that manipulates a nested dictionary. Intuition is correct, it takes less time when you have a reference to a nested dictionary. Here is the plot, read the details below to see how I got this.
[image: You can see keeping a reference takes less time]
With `_noRef` I am not keeping a reference to a nested dictionary. With `_ref` I am keeping a reference to nested dictionary. I am then running a for loop and adding members to nested dictionary in `add` and accessing them in `count`.

I am timing both with reference and without reference. Further to be sure of the pattern, I am repeating and getting multiple time values.

This is the script

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_noRef(d):
    for i in range(10000000):
        d['nested'][i] = 100*i

def add_Ref(d):
    r = d['nested']
    for i in range(10000000):
        r[i] = 100*i

def count_noRef(d):
    count = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        count += d['nested'][i]
    return count

def count_Ref(d):
    r = d['nested']
    count = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        count += r[i]
    return count 

def TEST_NO_REF(repeats):

    SETUP_CODE = '''
def add_noRef(d):
    for i in range(1000):
        d['nested'][i] = 100*i

def count_noRef(d):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        count += d['nested'][i]
    return count'''
    TEST_CODE = '''
d = dict()
d['nested'] = dict()
add_noRef(d)
x = count_noRef(d)
    '''
    # timeit.repeat statement
    times = timeit.repeat(setup = SETUP_CODE,
                          stmt = TEST_CODE,
                          repeat = repeats,
                          number = 10000)
    return times

def TEST_REF(repeats):

    SETUP_CODE = '''
def add_Ref(d):
    r = d['nested']
    for i in range(1000):
        r[i] = 100*i

def count_Ref(d):
    count = 0
    r = d['nested']
    for i in range(1000):
        count += d['nested'][i]
    return count'''
    TEST_CODE = '''
d = dict()
d['nested'] = dict()
add_Ref(d)
x = count_Ref(d)
    '''
    # timeit.repeat statement
    times = timeit.repeat(setup = SETUP_CODE,
                          stmt = TEST_CODE,
                          repeat = repeats,
                          number = 10000)
    return times
repeats = 10
X = [i for i in range(1,repeats+1)]
time_Norefs = TEST_NO_REF(repeats)
time_refs = TEST_REF(repeats)

plt.plot(X, time_Norefs)

plt.plot(X, time_refs)

plt.legend(["Without using reference to nested dict", "Using reference to nested dict"])

plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('time taken')
plt.title('Time taken to execute')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('timeTest.png')
```

Comment: @Manuel check now